# Guessing Game program. User thinks of number, computer tries to guess it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessHarder {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Random generator = new Random();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    String higher = "higher", lower = "lower", correct = "correct", input;
    int guess, random, random2 = 1, random3 = 100, randomLast, cntr = 1;

    random = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    randomLast = random;
    System.out.println("Is your number: " + random);
    System.out.println("Input if number should be higher, lower, or correct: ");
    input = reader.next();

    while (!input.equals("correct")){
        if (input.equals("lower")){
            randomLast = random2;
            random2 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
            if ((random2 < random) && (random2 < randomLast)){
            random = random2;
            cntr += 1;
            System.out.println("Is your number: " + random);
            System.out.println("Input if number should be higher, lower, or correct: ");
            input = reader.next();
            } else {
                input = lower;
            }
        } else if (input.equals("higher")){
            randomLast = random3;
            random3 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
            if ((random3 > random) && (random3 > randomLast)){
            random = random3;
            cntr += 1;
            System.out.println("Is your number: " + random);
            System.out.println("Input if number should be higher, lower, or correct: ");
            input = reader.next();
            } else {
                input = higher;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Computer took " + cntr + " amount of tries to guess your number");

    }
}
```

When I input higher or lower it will give me the number higher or lower than the previous respectively but it won't remember previous numbers.
For clarity an example would be:

"Is your number: 65

Input if number should be higher, lower, or correct:

*higher*

Is your number: 96

Input if number should be higher, lower, or correct:

*lower*

Is your number: 59

Input if number should be higher, lower, or correct:"

The range by the last input should have been 65-96, but instead it just does 0-96 so I get numbers like 59 that shouldn't be in the range.
What should I change to set it up to remember last two inputs for range instead of just the last.

Comment: The easiest solution would be remembering the current known upper bound and lower bound. So you start with `int upperBound = 100` and  `lower bound = 0`. With the user input you can then set the corresponding bound to the last given value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So keep two variables that "remember" the lower and upper bounds.

```
int lowerBound = 0;
int upperBound = MAX_NUMBER;
```

Then each time the computer makes a guess you need to update these two numbers.

Once you update the two numbers you need to generate a new guess based on those numbers.

```
generator.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound + 1) + lowerBound;
```

The `+1` makes the value inclusive.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `generator.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound;`? For example if `lowerBound` is 60 and `upperBound` is 80 your generator has a range from 80 to 140. Or do I misunderstand your both bound variables?

Comment: @Tom yes, it was actually like that, and I added `+1` to make it inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember the lower and the upper bound and try to make a random number between them instead of

```
generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
```